# TclError: can't invoke "canvas" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to run some code from the console, but am getting the TclError. Below is the entire traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "SM_analyser.py", line 446, in OnB_maxq
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.plotter, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 225, in __init__
    master=master, width=w, height=h, borderwidth=4)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2195, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'canvas', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2055, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: can't invoke "canvas" command:  application has been destroyed
```

I'm reasonably sure the the following block of code is responsible. It should be adding the plot 'figure' to a tkinter canvas, but when I run it 'figure' is plotted in a separate window and the Tcl error is given.

```
self.plotter = plt.figure('figure')            
plt.contour(array, linewidths = 1, colors = 'k')
plt.contourf(array, cmap = plt.cm.jet)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontdict = {'fontsize':16})
plt.xlabel('A', fontdict = {'fontsize':16})
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('figure', fontdict = {'fontsize':20})
plt.show()       
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.plotter, self)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=14,row=2,rowspan=34)
plt.close()
self.canvas._tkcanvas.config(highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: You are mixing the pyplot interface and embedding.  See http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html  I don't know enough about TK to do more than point you to that example and advise you to not import `pyplot` if you are doing embedding (due to the figure managers creating new windows and due to possible issues with the event loop).

Comment: @tcaswell I've tried to fix that before but to no avail. I can't find anywhere that plots a contour graph without pyplot. What is really strange is that my code runs perfectly from my interpreter (Spyder, not IDLE), but I get this error when I run it from the console.

Comment: almost all of the `pyplot` commands are more-or-less thin wrappers of the form `plt.foo(..)` <-> `plt.gca().foo(..)`.  If you have a reference to an `axes.Axes` object just call `contour` on it.

Comment: @tcaswell Ok so I generated a reference to the axes using `ax = self.plotter.gca()` and called contour on it. Works well, thanks. What is the correct way of adding the colourbar and contourf plot to the plot in this instance?

Comment: Those are figure methods so you just need to get a ref to a figure object (probably your `self.plotter`) and then `fig.colorbar()`.  You might need to also pass it a ref to the artist returned by `contourf`.

Answer (score 1):

`TclError: can't invoke "canvas" command:  application has been destroyed` means that you are trying to create an instance of a `Canvas` class, but that the main window of the application no longer exists. You might want to step through the logic of your program to see if you're destroying the root window at some point prior to creating the canvas.